# How can I filter filename patterns in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching

I need to do something similar to Unix's `ls | grep 'my[rR]egexp?'` in Powershell. The similar expression `ls | Select-String -Pattern 'my[rR]egexp?'` seems to go through *contents* of the listed files, rather than simply filtering the filenames themselves.

The [Select-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/43d70212-90e0-4a89-a148-04d7db9a7ab1%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) documentation hasn't been of much help either.

Comment: Note that `Select-String` patterns are case-insensitive by default.

Comment: @mikez: Not only `Select-String`. All of PowerShell (except when calling .NET methods directly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple:

```
ls | where Name -match 'myregex'
```

There are other options, though:

```
(ls) -match 'myregex'
```

Or, depending on how complex your regex is, you could maybe also solve it with a simple wildcard match:

```
ls wild[ck]ard*.txt
```

which is faster than above options. And if you can get it into a wildcard match without character classes you can also just use the `-Filter` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` (`ls`), which performs filtering on the file system level and thus is even faster. Note also that PowerShell is case-insensitive by default, so a character class like `[rR]` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, that's educative. How does the second method work though, are the parantheses a shortcut for some command? (btw the `[rR]` was just to illustrate it's a regex, my actual filter is based on `\d` and anchors)

Comment: The second method, the parentheses have the common programming/math "do this first" meaning; without them it would try and give -match as a parameter to `ls` but with them, it lists the files then does `-match` against the array of results.

Comment: The second one exploits a feature of PowerShell where comparison operators return matching results when there's a collection on the left side. `(ls)` first evaluates completely, yielding an array of results, `-match` is then applied for every one of them, trying to match the string representation (the name) to the regex, and returning those that match.

Answer (score 1):

While researching based on @Joey's answer, I stumbled upon another way to achieve the same (based on Select-String itself):

```
ls -Name | Select-String -Pattern 'my[Rr]egexp?'
```

The `-Name` argument seems to make `ls` return the result as a plain string rather than FileInfo object, so `Select-String` treats it as the string to be searched in rather than a list of files to be searched.

Comment: I'd really advise against this, though. PowerShell is designed to work with objects and while strings are objects, too, they're a poor substitute for richer ones, like `FileInfo`. Sure, you can go back to the Dark Age of Unix shell scripting, but you're missing out on a lot.

Comment: Haha yes, that was just my inner Unix geek finding comfort in a familiar plaintext pipe. Powershell's object functionalities do sound potentially much more powerful though, especially considering .NET is only a bracket away!